# Can Visual Studio Overwrite an Application?

Tags: .net

I have two Visual Studio vb.NET applications. Previously, I have published each application separately as application A and application B. Recently, I rewrote application A to encorporate both A & B. Now I would like B to point to A, so if the users have either A or B on their computers, both applications will load application A. How can I do this?

Comment: elaborate please. What sort of applications?

Comment: Well, no reason to make this complicated.  Just create a little project with the same name as B that does nothing but Process.Start() the A app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about ClickOnce applications then you'd want to replace B with a small program to launch the application file for A.  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start would probably do this.  Not sure whether that will work for online files.  There might be something more specific in System.Deployment for launching ClickOnce applications.